# Register work to object and make it executable every 5 minutes

Tags: nestjs

So i have the following case, user is creating random object at random time. Every time when object is created i want to attach function to the object and this function must be executable every 5 minutes. I'm using nestjs and there is `ScheduleModule`  module which allow me to call a function from service every 5 minutes. Work is there let's say one of the object is created 5 minutes ago and yes he must do the job but we have another object which is created 2 minutes ago and he do not need to execute the operation yet cuz 5 minutes are not passed.

My questions is how we can attach job to every object when is created and make it executable every 5 minutes independently from the other objects using `nestjs`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have the most luck working with some kind of queuing system so that you can dynamically register work to be executed some time in the future. One popular option is the [NestJS Bull Queue module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues#queues)

With this you can register jobs at runtime that have a 5 minute delay on them whenever a new object is created in your system:

```
const job = await this.jobQueue.add('objectCreated', {
  // payload can be whatever data you want to pass to job handler
}, { delay: 5000 });
```